# Converting in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I have two related ComboBoxes using following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Frm_Evr_Scoring : Form
{

    public Frm_Evr_Scoring()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        //*************  ******************
        CurrentUser.CUser = "4";
        CurrentUser.CexeP = "9";
        //*************  ******************
        refreshDept();

    }
    public void refreshDept()
    {
        _360_OLDDataContext db = new _360_OLDDataContext();
        var Dept = from ep in db.ExecutivePosts
                    join ea in db.ExePostAllocates on ep.ID equals 
                    ea.ExePostID
                    join u in db.Units on ep.UnitID equals u.ID
                    join dept in db.Departments on u.DeptID equals dept.ID
                    where ea.PrsID == Convert.ToInt32(CurrentUser.CUser)
                    select new { dept.ID, dept.Title };
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
            {
                DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
                ColumnName = "DeptID"
            }
            );
        DT.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
            {
                DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
                ColumnName = "DeptTitle"
            }
            );
        foreach (var item in Dept)
        {
            var row = DT.NewRow();
            row["DeptID"] = item.ID;
            row["DeptTitle"] = item.Title;
            DT.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        DataRow DR;
        DR = DT.NewRow();
        DR.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "... ... ... ... ... ..." };
        DT.Rows.InsertAt(DR, 0);
        Cmb_evr_Dept.DataSource = DT;
        Cmb_evr_Dept.ValueMember = "DeptID";
        Cmb_evr_Dept.DisplayMember = "DeptTitle";
    }
    private void Cmb_evr_Dept_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
        {
            int D =Convert.ToInt32(Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue);
            refreshUnit(D);
        }
    }
    public void refreshUnit(int DeptID)
    {
        _360_OLDDataContext db = new _360_OLDDataContext();
        var Unit = from ea in db.ExePostAllocates
                   join ep in db.ExecutivePosts on ea.ExePostID equals ep.ID
                   join u in db.Units on ep.UnitID equals u.ID
                   join d in db.Departments on u.DeptID equals d.ID
                   where d.ID == DeptID && ea.PrsID == Convert.ToInt32(CurrentUser.CUser)
                   select u;

        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
            {
                DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
                ColumnName = "UnitID",
            }
        );
        DT.Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn()
            {
                DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
                ColumnName = "UnitTitle",
            }
        );
        foreach (var item in Unit)
        {
            var row = DT.NewRow();
            row["UnitID"] = item.ID;
            row["UnitTitle"] = item.Title;
            DT.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        DataRow DR;
        DR = DT.NewRow();
        DR.ItemArray = new object[] {0, "... ... ... ... ... ..." };
        DT.Rows.InsertAt(DR, 0);
        Cmb_evr_Unit.DataSource = DT;
        Cmb_evr_Unit.ValueMember = "UnitID";
        Cmb_evr_Unit.DisplayMember = "UnitTitle";
    }
```

The problem is here:

```
private void Cmb_evr_Dept_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
    {
        int D =Convert.ToInt32(Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue);
        refreshUnit(D);
    }
}
```

when it is going to convert "Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue" to "int" I receive this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code, with these datails:
>   {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'."}

What is weird for me is that when I use this line:

```
int D =Convert.ToInt32(Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue);
```

in another lines like behind a Button Click Event to show in a TextBox, it shows no problem.
Would someone help me out with this please? I am really puzzled!
Thanks.

Another question, what is the difference between the LINQ query (var Dept) in the beginning of the refreshDept() method and the following:

```
_360_OLDDataContext db = new _360_OLDDataContext();
        ExecutivePost ep1 = db.ExecutivePosts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 
Convert.ToInt32(CurrentUser.CexeP));
        Unit UUU = db.Units.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == ep1.UnitID);
        Department DDD = db.Departments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 
UUU.DeptID);
        var Dept1 = from d in db.Departments where d.ID == DDD.ID select new 
{ d.ID, d.Title };
```

It doesn't work for me!

And if it can be corrected, which of them are more efficient? the LINQ query containing many joins OR the last one?

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what `Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue` is when the exception occurs.

Comment: `Cmb_evr_Dept.SelectedValue.ToString() != null` come for the cargo, stay for the bamboo aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are first setting the `DataSource` and after that you set the `ValueMember` and the `DisplayMember`. What is happening is that in the moment you set he `DataSource`, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised and as `ValueMember` is not set, `SelectedValue` is a `DataRowView`. Just change the order and it should work:

```
Cmb_evr_Dept.ValueMember = "DeptID";
Cmb_evr_Dept.DisplayMember = "DeptTitle"; 
Cmb_evr_Dept.DataSource = DT;

Cmb_evr_Unit.ValueMember = "UnitID";
Cmb_evr_Unit.DisplayMember = "UnitTitle";
Cmb_evr_Unit.DataSource = DT;
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for the edit. My brain suffered a shortcircuit it seems :)

Comment: Thank you very very much dears.

Comment: Would you please answer my "Another Question"?